# How do i stop loops getting in the way of the rest of my code?

Tags: python, while-loop

**how do i stop this loop getting in the way of the rest of my code? i have had to make this project for one of my assignments so any help would be greatly appreciated. So ive put a "while True" statement in the code to restart the program if the user inputs a number outside of the specified range, but it gets in the way of the rest of the code if the user enters a correct number within the specified range. how can i keep this feature in place but not have it get in the way of the rest of the code?**

```
for i in range (99999):
hat_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # This is an existing list of numbers hidden in the hat.

print("the current list is", hat_list)
new_number = int(input("enter a number between 6 and 10 to replace the middle number '3': "))


# Step 1: write a line of code that prompts the user
# to replace the middle number with an integer number entered by the user.

while True:
if new_number >= 10: print("you have entered a number outside of the specified range. Try 
again")
elif new_number <= 6: print("you have entered a number outside of the specified range. Try 
again")
continue 


if new_number == 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10: print("correct number(s) entered")
hat_list[2] = new_number


# Step 2: write a line of code that removes the last element from the list.
del hat_list[4]
print("the last number of the list is now deleted")

# Step 3: write a line of code that prints the length of the new / updated list.

print("the list is now: ", hat_list)
print("and the length of it is: ", len(hat_list), "lines long \n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
```

Comment: The answer to this question involves indentation, but it's hard to show you how to fix your code since you removed all the indentation when you pasted it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned this is your assignment so I cant give you the full solution.
But I believe you have to use break statement within the while loop just to break out of the loop.

Here is the doc for it.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Answer (score 0):

`While True` runs forever until you exit from the loop. You can break the loop by using the keyword `break`

```
while True:
  if new_number >= 10:
    print("you have entered a number outside of the specified range. Try again")
    break
  elif new_number <= 6:
    print("you have entered a number outside of the specified range. Try again")
```

Comment: I have fixed the code by making the initial `while` statement `while x == 0:` and keeping the `if` and `elif` for the criteria of incorrect input with noting else attached to them eg... `continue` or `break`. Then for the correct criteria to proceed i have put  `else: print("correct number(s) entered"), x = 1` now everything runs as i want. Thank you for your help though.